# What happens when a paddr_t is passed to a linked list that is expecting unsigned on a 64bit system?

Tags: c++, parameters, parameter-passing

**After looking harder at the code, I figured out the answer to my question. I was mistaken in thinking the initial declaration of linked list meant all future types had to be the same**

The code I am looking at is for linked list insertion. The linked list is used to store logical addresses. The linked list is defined as unsigned 32 bit, but the addresses being inserted are defined as void*.

A logical address is cast to paddr_t and is then inserted. paddr_t was used to be reverse compatible with 32bit or 64 bit systems, since the void* size changes.

When the paddr_t is passed to the insert function, will the insert function parameter be promoted to paddr_t? Will the linked list member be promoted as well once the insertion is complete?

Abbreviated example of the code

```
LinkedList <unsigned> foo;
unsigned bar = 1001;
void* Laddr = &bar;
foo.insert((paddr_t)Laddr);
```

Comment: If, through pointers, you pretend a value is of a different type than what it really is, then *strict aliasing* is broken and you will have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: I would say undefined behavior or the behavior is platform dependent.  Converting from a 64-bit address to a 32-bit address involves the loss of information.

Comment: What does the parameter of `insert()` mean?  Is it an integer to be stored in the list, or does `insert()` treat it as an address, and copy the value at that address into the list?

Comment: To really be able to answer you, a [mre] will be needed. `paddr_t` isn't a standard type in C++ nor in POSIX. Your `LinkedList` template, what is the signature of the `insert` function? What is `sizeof(void*)`?

Comment: You shouldn't need to define a new type `paddr_t` to cope with changes in the size of `void*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a common-sense definition of `LinkedList`: You don't pass `paddr_t` to the insert function. You pass `unsigned` to the insert function. If you try to pass `paddr_t`, the compiler will add an `(unsigned)` cast for you, and may or may not emit a warning.

If `paddr_t` and `unsigned` are the same type, it's unlikely that you'll get a warning, and extremely likely that it will work fine.

If `paddr_t` is bigger than `unsigned`, and you have a `paddr_t` that doesn't fit in an `unsigned`, then the extra bits will be removed to make it fit in `unsigned`, and that number will be stored in the list, and whatever code get the number back *out* of the list and converts it back to `paddr_t` will not work properly because it gets the wrong number.